# Searching through selenium and counting the number of times a particular string appears except if the string appears twice in a row

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to count the number of times that a particular element appears inside of the webpage, and I'm doing that using `int size = driver.getPageSource().split("pager__item").length-1`.

The issue is that sometimes inside of the webpage, the string that I am looking for appears twice in a row.  It appears twice because there's a page number display down at the bottom, which contains "next page" and "last".

In these particular elements, the string is `pager__item pager__item--next`, which is counted as two when I only want it to count as 1.  In the rest of the webpage, the string is only displayed as `pager__item`.

Comment: So it is a logic design problem, and has nothing to do with Selenium specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest removing the "pager__item--next", then count.

```
String pageSrc = driver.getPageSource().replaceAll("pager__item--next","");
int size = pageSrc.split("pager__item").length-1;
```